# Web Service Access Denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, access-denied

I have a problem with web service against Internet Explorer 7 or 8
I have a web application (ASP.Net), contain a page with textbox extends an autocompleteextender which fire a web service to retrieve the category list from SQL DB.
The problem come after upgrading my IE from version 6 to 7
it give me an "access denied" error.
Before that it is work normal with ie 6
I tried the application in some other PCs
if the IE version is 6, it work normally
if not (IE7 or IE8), it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the address of this service to the trusted zone in IE7 or IE8

Have you seen this posts : [post1](http://forums.asp.net/p/1241699/2269911.aspx) [post2](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2007/01/31/how-to-work-around-the-quot-access-denied-quot-cross-domain-frame-issue-in-asp-net-ajax-1-0.aspx)

Comment: thank you "B-Rain" for answering to my question
but unfortunately, I have already added it
can you help me to workaround this problem
which come after upgrading to IE7